# Meaning of {1:>2} in python programme of printing tables

Tags: python

In shown `print` statement,
What is the meaning of

> {1:>2}

```
 print("{1:>2} times {0} is {2}".format(i,j,i*j),file=tables)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1` is the the first argument, followed by formatting rules. In this case, it means that we pad the number by adding spaces to the left of it, until the result is 2 characters wide. This is useful if you want to print a lot of information in the same format into the same file and want the result to be readable. For more information, have a look [here](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below examples,

```
>>> print("{1:>2} times {0} is {2}".format(2,3,2*3))         
 3 times 2 is 6
>>> print("{1:>4} times {0} is {2}".format(2,3,2*3))         
   3 times 2 is 6
>>> print("{1:>8} times {0} is {2}".format(2,3,2*3))         
       3 times 2 is 6
>>> print("{1:<8} times {0} is {2}".format(2,3,2*3))         
3        times 2 is 6
>>> print("{1:>8} times {0} is {2}".format(2,3,2*3))         
       3 times 2 is 6
>>>
```

Now you can understand that, it is used to add space around the element your printing.

```
> - Add space to left side
< - Add space to right side

   # {element:left|right number_of_spaces}
```

Answer (score 0):

this script creates math tables

```
> for i in range(2, 13):
>     for j in range(1, 13): 
>         print('{1:>2} times {0} is {2}'.format(i, j, i * j))
```

explanation

number of tables: table of 2, table of 3 ...etc

```
for i in range(2, 13):



lines in each individual table
for j in range(1, 13):

    what is printed in each line
    print('{1:>2} times {0} is {2}'.format(i, j, i * j))
```

now
{1:>2} says that  j is right justified

example of expression = print('{0} and{1} and {2}'.format(a, b, c))    where {0} =a,  {1} =b and  {2} = c.

{1: > 2} 1 in this expression correspond to  j , {0} to i and {2} correspond to i*j = the order of appearance was changed from {0} {1}  {2}  to  {1}, {0} and {2}.

There is a confusion because while constructing the expression instead of {0} {1}  {2} the coder used {1}, {0} and {2}, in this case {1} was changed to {1:>2) and '2' is the numbers of spaces from the beginning of paragraph and  '>' means right justified. So {j} is right justified  two spaces.